# Step functions - split array and process synchronously

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have set up a step function state machine which calls two separate lambda functions. The general process I would like to achieve is:

1. Trigger first lambda to make an api call. This will respond with a list of ids eg `[1,2,3,4,5, ...]`
2. Chunk array into smaller sizes and then process ids one by one to make another api call. Given the size of the response from step 1 and the duration of api calls, this has the potential to go over the 15min max timeout for a lambda function. So I would like to chunk this up so each chunk of the list is processed by its own lambda function.
3. Preferably the invocation of lambdas in step 2 would not occur at the same time. Ideally the lambda would process the first chunk -> shut down, then a new lambda function is invoked with the 2nd chunk, process/shut down, etc...

I've looked into the array partition intrinsic function that can do the chunking, however I'm not sure how to invoke and process the 2nd lambda step sequentially.

Comment: Use a [Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) state with `MaxConcurrency: 1` to process each item in an array with a individual Lambda task, serially.  See Option #1 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305901/1103511).